# How do I assign a value to an unbound textbox when opening report in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, report, ms-access-2013

I am using Access 2013 and have a report that I am trying to set the values of eight unbound textboxes when it gets opened.  In the code I have written so far, I have opened a recordset and used it to calculate the value of eight items. This part of code works fine.  Now I want to get these eight values into the report where they will be used in a calculation.

The first unbound textbox name in the report is "CivPistonUnder"

Here is the code:

```
Dim strDocName As String
Dim lngPistonUnder As Long

strDocName = "rptAWMP"
DoCmd.OpenReport strDocName, acViewPreview, , , acWindowNormal
'this is where I want to set the value of the unbound textbox
'I have tried
Me.CivPistonUnder = lngPistonUnder
'I get a compilation error: Method or data member not found
'I tried
Set CivPistonUnder = lngPistonUnder
'I get Compile error: Object required
'I tried
Set Report.rptAWMP!CivPistonUnder = lngPistonUnder
'I get Object Required
```

Is there a way to pass this info to the report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't manipulate data on a report after it has been opened in print preview. It simulates printing, you can't change anything after it has been sent to the printer too. :)

You must do this in a report event, e.g. `Report_Load`.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
    ' This will work
    Me.txtUnbound.Value = "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

To pass the values to the event procedure, you can e.g. use TempVars, or a Public array / collection.

Comment: Andre, okay the analogy of changing something that has been printed totally makes sense.  Thankyou. My code is already in a private sub that was based on clicking a button in a form and creating/opening this report.  How would I move to or point to another private sub to open the report using the 8 variables that I have calculated here?

Comment: See the last line in my answer, or move the whole code to the report, or use a public Sub where you pass `Me` from Report_Load as report object.

Comment: It helps to put your code in the right area!  I moved the code from the on click event of a form that opens the report to the on load of the report itself and voila! Appreciate your help Andre.  I was banging my head against a wall and could no longer see the way forward.